# JS: How to combine Object from two different arrays into one Array/Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, array-push, array-reduce

If have two arrays (content & ids) which i need to combine in one array (combined).

**First Array:**

```
let content = [
  { "Name": "Max Mustermann" },
  { "Name": "Berta Beispiel" },
  { "Name": "Zacharias Zufall" }
]
```

**Second Array:**

```
let ids = [
  "12345678-1", 
  "12345678-2", 
  "12345678-3"
]
```

Which should combined look like this:

```
let combined = [
  {
    "Name": "Max Mustermann",
    "id": "12345678-1"
  },
    {
    "Name": "Berta Beispiel",
    "id": "12345678-2"
  },
    {
    "Name": "Zacharias Zufall",
    "id": "12345678-3"
  }
]
```

I tried different things from push, reduce, map.... but nothing worked: :(

Comment: Show what you tried.... Could have been a simple typo or a slight issue with logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need, something as simple as this could work. Note: it modifies the original `content` array.

```js
let content = [
  { "Name": "Max Mustermann" },
  { "Name": "Berta Beispiel" },
  { "Name": "Zacharias Zufall" }
]

let ids = [
  "12345678-1", 
  "12345678-2", 
  "12345678-3"
];

for(let i=0;i<content.length;i++) {
  content[i].id = ids[i] || null;
}

console.log(content);
```

If you need to create a new object + new array from the two, you can use

```js
const content = [
  { "Name": "Max Mustermann" },
  { "Name": "Berta Beispiel" },
  { "Name": "Zacharias Zufall" }
]

const ids = [
  "12345678-1", 
  "12345678-2", 
  "12345678-3"
];

const merged = content.map((c, index) => ({id: ids[index] || null, ...c}));
console.log(merged);
```

It really depends more on you and the context of the situation.

### Edit

I'd feel like I wasn't doing my duty if I didn't mention that in Javascript the difference between `let` and `const` in reference to arrays or objects is a bit muddled.

The following is perfectly valid JS with the `const` declaration:

```
const items = [];
items.push(1,2,3);
console.log(items); // 1, 2, 3
```

This is because the `const` refers to some more complicated information that you can look up as you understand more of the language itself. In the future, however, the basic thing you need to ask yourself when determining whether or not you should use `const` or `let` is this:

> Will I need to totally reassign the variable at some point? e.g.

```
arr = [1,2,3]; 
/// code later on;
arr = [5,6,7];
```

If so, use `let`. But if your code looks more like

```
arr = [1,2,3];
// other stuff
arr.push(4,5,6);
arr.pop();
arr.sort((a,b) => a-b);
```

Then you are likely OK with using `const`.

I know this isn't the best clarification, but speaking more in depth would about it might cause more confusion since I don't know your level of programming knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

It should work:

```js
let content = [
  { "Name": "Max Mustermann" },
  { "Name": "Berta Beispiel" },
  { "Name": "Zacharias Zufall" }
]
let ids = [
  "12345678-1", 
  "12345678-2", 
  "12345678-3"
]
let combined = content.map((cnt, index) => {
  let idPart = {
    id: ids[index],
  };
  return {...cnt, ...idPart};
});
// Short version:
/*
let combined = content.map((c, i) => ({id: ids[i], ...c}));
*/
```